# aiogram event handling not working dispatcher

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, telegram-api

I am trying to get updates:

```
dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.update()
async def message_handler(update: types.Update):
    print(update)
```

But it doesn't work and nothing is output to the console

I need to intercept any events and make it so that other handlers like @dp.message work

Comment: What's incomprehensible here? I need event handling and it doesn't work. If update handled any events, I would do what is needed

Comment: A lot of things: for example, we don't know what you've really done so far (your code is too short for us to help, and we need a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), plus you haven't given any software version information.  I recommend you check out SO's page on [ask].

Comment: Also, please read the [tour] page, since you haven't yet.